# fopen issue in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, fopen

For some reason fopen gives the error `No such file or directory` even though I have converted the path to the documents path.

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

I pass the NSString using the `UTF8String` method and only open in read mode with

```
if ((fh=fopen(filename, "r+b")) == NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    return -1;
}
```

The following full path is printed out when trying to open the filename(I removed the exact values for the applications actual dir name)

> /var/mobile/Applications/#####/Documents/testImages.pak

Why would fopen not detect the file? I have added it to the target and even tried changing the location settings in the file inspector to `Relative to Group` and `Relative to Project`

Comment: How about opening filePath instead of filename?

Comment: The filename variable is within the C API itself. The obj c code is in a wrapper. I pass the filePath with UTF8String to the c function expecting a char *

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I would suggest using the native NSFileManager and NSFileHandle, they should be good for almost anything fopen does.

Comment: Does the file actually exist in the documents directory? How does it get there?

Comment: If you do this in the simulator (or if you **are** doing it in the simulator), can you see the actual file at the given path?

Comment: Im testing on the real device. NSLogging the docs dir shows no files. When I then pass the [filename UTF8String] with no path it still doesnt find the file. Is it possible to NSLog all resources with their paths?

Comment: @Helium3 When you connect the device, in xcode => Organizer => Devices you can look at the doc-dir.

Comment: Great. Library contains files, but not the resource file. I have set it to be added to target. Where would a resource be added to the app Bundle?

Comment: This is a side issue, but you should use `-fileSystemRepresentation` instead of `-UTF8String` to get a C string suitable for C library file APIs or syscalls.

Comment: Thanks. I tried fileSystemRepresentation but still get no file or directory. Im not sure what is going on. I removed the file and added it to xcode again, copying contents, adding to target as usual. I have never come across such an issue, but I have never used fopen directly in an obj c project before.

Comment: I just checked for the file in main bundle and it exists. For some reason passing the filename as is, the exact same name as the printed filename, fopen cant find it. I have tried ./ and / infront of the filename, no luck.

Comment: So you are constructing a path in your documents directory but the file you want to open is in your app bundle?

Comment: @Sven - The latest is that the path is now correct. When fopen now attempts to open the file with the path constructed like so:NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *filePath = [bundleRoot stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]; there is an error :fopen: Operation not permitted

Comment: Of course. You are not allowed to write to files inside your app bundle.

Comment: @Helium3 Use the standard procedure for writable copies: If the file does not exist in the doc-dir, copy it there from the resource-dir. There you can write to the file.

Answer (score 12):

You have to convert the NSString to a char* using the following method, or it will not properly map to the file system.

```
    char const *path_cstr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:pathString];
```

Now you can use it directly in fopen().

Comment: Thanks man. I was scratching my head for 1 day now why it wouldn't work on iOS 10 and this answer helped.