# Error using a file path in fopen on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, fopen

I'm new to Objective-C, and I have the following problem in this code:

```
NSLog(@"Path: %@", _nomFile); //show--> Path: /Users/heberthdeza/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/75184CE7-6CCD-4E5E-ABD1-E150CB35164E/Documents/discovery/IOS-4F55A50D-A3C7-4090-9969-F186C0501F89-23172117.zvg
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen([_nomFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"rb");
if (fp==NULL) {
  NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
```

`fopen` always returns `NULL` (and shows "ERROR"). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: consider using [_nomFile UTF8String] instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding

Comment: @Wagner: based on what? There seem to be no high ASCII characters in that path -- not unless some of the characters are actually en-dashes or omicrons or such.

Comment: I've tried and does not work, any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't even try to solve his problem... I just put as a comment so he can avoid future errors... in fact, it doesn't have to do anything with the problem... I just thought he could have CHANGED the path string when posting the question here to hide some particular information... maybe there could be a UTF-8 character...

Comment: @kiddie: does it work correctly with any other file?

Comment: @Jongware I have not tried with other files, but this is a text file with an extension enzipado ZVG, simple.

Comment: include <errno.h> and add NSLog(@"ERROR %d", errno); to your if (fp == NULL) test, then tell us the value, also adding a printf("%s\n", [_nomFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) to check what is returned might be a not so bad idea

Comment: May be it is not possible to open a `.ZVG` extension files in `iOS`, try to open some other files! and just take a look at this question on how they have passed the file path http://stackoverflow.com/a/10671176/1059705

Comment: I'm not sure what you're use case is here, but why use fopen over NSFileManager if you're writing an iOS app?

Comment: sorry friends, it was a false alarm, was trying to access the file before it exists, and I solved it by just moving this code to the right place. Sorry.